# need to check innerHTML and remove parent li

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a similar problem (tried to see if I could use the provided solution here - but not). My HTML-code looks like this:

```
<ol class="browse-catalogue">
    <li>
        <a href="/baby/girls/tshirts-tops" catid="26,251820" sw="1">
            T-shirts & toppe
            <span class="count"> (3)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/baby/girls/shirts-blouses" catid="26,251821" sw="1">
            Skjorter & bluser
            <span class="count"> (0)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/baby/girls/jeans" catid="26,251822" sw="1">
            Jeans
            <span class="count"> (0)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I am trying to write some javascript code that checks every span class="count" innerHTML if it is equal to `(0)`, if then should remove the `li` container it's sitting in.

This is how my javascript code looks like (but does not work unfortunately):

```
function removeSubcatalog () {
    // removing subcatalogs if they are empty:

    var checkEmpty=document.getElementsByClassName("count");
    var parent=checkEmpty.parentNode;
    if (checkEmpty.innerHTML == " (0)"){
        parent.removeParentNode;
    };
}  
removeSubcatalog();
```

Hope someone in here can guide me in the right direction
Thanks,
Mogens

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list. You have to iterate through the elements and work on each one individually.

Answer (score 3):

First, [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [html collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not a single element reference so you need to iterate and process each element in the collection. Also the collection is a [live one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_sometimes-live_collection), so you need to get a non-live collection - here I used a simple hack to convert the live collection to an real array, but there are other solutions like using `var els = document.questSelectorAll('.count')` or using a reverse loop(`for(var i = els.length - 1; i>= 0; i--)`).

You need to remove the parent's parent

```js
function removeSubcatalog() {
  var els = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("count"));
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    var checkEmpty = els[i];
    if (checkEmpty.innerHTML.trim() == "(0)") {
      checkEmpty.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
    };
  }
}
removeSubcatalog();
```

```html
<ol class="browse-catalogue">
  <li>
    <a href="/baby/girls/tshirts-tops" catid="26,251820" sw="1">
      T-shirts & toppe
      <span class="count"> (3)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/baby/girls/shirts-blouses" catid="26,251821" sw="1">
      Skjorter & bluser
      <span class="count"> (0)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/baby/girls/jeans" catid="26,251822" sw="1">
      Jeans
      <span class="count"> (0)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

---

But if you are using jQuery it is as simple as

```js
$('.count:contains("(0)")').closest('li').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="browse-catalogue">
  <li>
    <a href="/baby/girls/tshirts-tops" catid="26,251820" sw="1">
      T-shirts & toppe
      <span class="count"> (3)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/baby/girls/shirts-blouses" catid="26,251821" sw="1">
      Skjorter & bluser
      <span class="count"> (0)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/baby/girls/jeans" catid="26,251822" sw="1">
      Jeans
      <span class="count"> (0)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Comment: `String.prototype.trim()` is relativelly new. You should use a clunky `.replace(/\s*((?:.|\r|\n)*)\s*/g,'$1')` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, following is what you're trying to do ( without jQuery) :

```
    <script>
        function removeSubcatalog () {
            // removing subcatalogs if they are empty:

            var checkEmpty=document.getElementsByClassName("count");

            /* getElementsByClassName returns a collection, so we need a loop */
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < checkEmpty.length; i++){
                var countElem = checkEmpty[i];
                var parentLi = countElem.parentNode.parentNode; // parent is <a> and it's parent is <li>
                if (countElem.innerHTML.trim() == "(0)"){  // trimming, so that we don't have to worry about spaces
                    parentLi.remove();
                    i--; // since the array indices change as the elements gets removed
                };  
            }

        }  
    </script>

    <ol class="browse-catalogue">
        <li>
            <a href="/baby/girls/tshirts-tops" catid="26,251820" sw="1">
            T-shirts & toppe
                <span class="count"> (3)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/baby/girls/shirts-blouses" catid="26,251821" sw="1">
            Skjorter & bluser
                <span class="count"> (0)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/baby/girls/jeans" catid="26,251822" sw="1">
            Jeans
                <span class="count"> (0)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>

    <input type="button" onclick="removeSubcatalog()" value="delete"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in `JQuery` then it's very simple to do it by simple code.

- First get all span by class 'count'
- iterate all the span and check for its text
- it text is `(0)` then remove its parent `li`

JQuery code:

```
  var counts = $('.count');
  $.each(counts, function(i,item){
      if($(this).text() == ' (0)'){
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();   
      }
  });
```

Sample code:

```html
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <ol class="browse-catalogue">
            <li>
            <a href="/baby/girls/tshirts-tops" catid="26,251820" sw="1">
            T-shirts & toppe
            <span class="count"> (3)</span>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="/baby/girls/shirts-blouses" catid="26,251821" sw="1">
            Skjorter & bluser
            <span class="count"> (0)</span>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="/baby/girls/jeans" catid="26,251822" sw="1">
            Jeans
            <span class="count"> (0)</span>
            </a>
            </li>
              
              <button id="remove">Remove all zeros</button>
              
            <script>
          $('#remove').click(function(){
             var counts = $('.count');
             $.each(counts, function(i,item){
              if($(this).text() == ' (0)'){
              $(this).parent().parent().remove();   
              }
             });
          });
            </script>
```

Comment: `$(".count").each( ... )`

Comment: that's also a way to iterate all span having class `count`